# Multiple CheckBox Filter using Angular have any source code

Tags: angular, filter

I want to make filter based on city and gender using checkboxes if any one have code or similar code then help

Comment: If you're asking about mat-table and filter with severals conditions, take a look this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495473/how-to-add-multiple-filters-in-angular-mat-table/68496521#68496521) else, please, edit your question and give us more data to we can help you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.