# How to use dynamic filters in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, filter

i'm trying to understand the logic behind using filters in Angular but im finding hard to configure it. I red about dynamic filters but i didn't understand how to use those.
I hope you could give me some help.

I have a showcaseComponent where i wish to add three filters (Name, Description, Category) as text-type.

I type something like "Hello" in the Name filter and it shows me all the elements with "Hello" in the name for example.

I didn't find a proper guide that explain me step-by-step how to implement filters.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Jany. Angular works on observables, so a good approach are always observables. You can think in an [observable](https://angular.io/guide/comparing-observables) as a function that return an object or an array in "async mode" (you don't get it also when you subscribe to it)

If you have three "inputs", we began create a FormGroup using [ReactiveForms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) with this

```
form=new FormGroup({
  name:new FormControl(''),
  description:new FormControl(''),
  category:new FormControl(''),
})
```

A formGroup have a property that it's an Observable: valueChanges.

Now depend from your data and what are you using. If you use a simple array you can return an observable in this way

```
myWholeArray=[{...},{....},{...},...]
myArrayObservable$=this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith({name:'',description:'',category:''}),
    switchMap(res:any)>={
     //here you have an object of type {name:...,description:...,category:...}

     //if we have no input any value
     if (!res.name && !res.description && !res.catagory)
        return of(this.myWholeArray)
     
     //else you filter your array
     return of(
         this.myWholeArray.filter((x:any)=>{
             bool fulfilled=(res.name && x.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(res.name.toUpperCase())
             fulfilled=fullfilled && (res.description && x.description .toUpperCase().indexOf(res.description .toUpperCase())
             fulfilled=fulfilled && (res.category&& x.category.toUpperCase().indexOf(res.category.toUpperCase())

             return fullfilled;

         })
     )
}))
```

As you have an observable you indicate in the .html some like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myArrayObservable$|async>
   {{item.name}} {{item.description}} {{item.category}}
</div>
```

Yes, I know I was too much quickly. So step by step

- When we have an observable we can makes some operations over it. This
  "operations" are the `rxjs/operators`. This operators get one (or
  several) observable and transform in another one and we use using
  `pipe`and the operators separated by commas, like

  ```
     observable.pipe(firstOperator(res),secondOperator(res),...)
  ```
- The first operator is `startWith`. One observable only show the value
  is you subscribe to it. Yo can subscribe explicitaly (by code using
  `subscribe`) or using the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe). As we want use this
  observable, we "initialize" giving an initial value.
- The second operator is `switchMap`. switchMap transform one
  observable in another. So we transform the "valueChanges" in another
  observable. We need import this two operators `import {startWith,switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators'`
- See that we need return an observable, so it's not valid return an
  array. To return an observable when we have an object or an array we
  use the third operator `of` (as is an creation operator, we need
  `import {of} from 'rxjs'`)

Well. If you're using material and MatTableDataSource, the "property" filter makes the most part of work form you. See, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72353918/angular-material-table-multiple-filterpredicate/72361956#72361956)

You create the form and subscribe to valuesChanges

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((res) => {
  this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(res);
});
```

And create a custom function

Comment: Wow this is a huge help, thank you so much! I'm gonna read all the content of your answer carefully and then i'll try this approach! Thank you again :D