# Search filter in a material angular table for each column

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm very demoralized because I've been trying to do something for days without success.
I'm trying to create a search filter for each column I have in my table (filled dynamically, except the columns name).

I've created my table, gilled with data from an api, but now I have no idea how to filter column by column according to an input inserted from some box above.

**This is an example of what I would like.**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5kgg.png)

**P.s. I'm using angular and typescript**

Answer (score 0):

In this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495473/how-to-add-multiple-filters-in-angular-mat-table/68496521#68496521) there're an answer to give you some clues:

1. Create a formGroup
2. In subscribe equal the `dataSource.filter` to an string, the
   `JSON.stringify(res);`
3. create a function `customFilter` that received a element and the
   "filter" (the string before that you should parse using `JSON.parse`
   ) and return true if mtach with the values

**Update** Using the "typical" Periodic elements, we can use a FormGroup in the way

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    position: new FormControl(''),
    name: new FormControl(''),
    weight: new FormControl(''),
    symbol: new FormControl(''),
    filterOn: new FormControl(false),
  });
```

See that we can use a FormControl "filterOn". So, we can use a custom filter like

```
  customFilter = (data: PeriodicElement, filter: string) => {
    const filterData = JSON.parse(filter);
    let ok: boolean = true;
    if (!filterData.filterOn) return true;
    if (filterData.position) ok = data.position == filterData.position;
    if (filterData.name)
      ok = ok && data.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterData.name) >= 0;
    if (filterData.weight)
      ok = ok && ('' + data.weight).indexOf(filterData.weight) >= 0;
    if (filterData.symbol)
      ok = ok && data.symbol.toUpperCase().indexOf(filterData.symbol) >= 0;
    return ok;
  };
```

Ah!, when we subscribe to valueChanges, we transform to upperCase or another way our values

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.customFilter;
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((res: any) => {
      res.name = res.name.toUpperCase();
      res.symbol = res.symbol.toUpperCase();
      res.weight = '' + res.weight;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(res);
    });
  }
```

The button filter toggle the variable "filterOn" and use setValue to give value to the formControl "filterOn"

```
  filterToggle() {
    this.filterOn = !this.filterOn;
    this.form.controls.filterOn.setValue(this.filterOn);
  }
```

The [whole stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aajfzz?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts)