# Multiple Filters on MatTable Angular

Tags: angular

I've been trying to apply multi column filtering i.e a text input in column headers will filter only on the contents of the column. So far I tried to filter `client_name` and `module_controle` columns but that doesn't seem to work, I lose all my array data (I have an empty array). I have no error in my console.

Here is my code home.component.html:

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="module_control">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Module control
          <div>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="moduleControlFilter" placeholder="Filter" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"/>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.module_control}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="client_name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Client name
          <div>
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="clientNameFilter" placeholder="Filter" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"/>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.client_name}} </td>
      </ng-container>

          ......

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></tr>
    </table>
```

Home.component.ts:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['module_control', "client_name"];
  customers!: Customer[];

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>(this.customers)

  clientNameFilter = new FormControl();
  moduleControlFilter = new FormControl();

  filteredValues = { 
    client_name: '',
    module_control: '',
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) matSort! : MatSort;

  constructor(private customerService: customerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.moduleControlFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((moduleControlFilterValue) => {
      this.filteredValues['module_control'] = moduleControlFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
    });

    this.clientNameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe((ClientNameFilterValue) => {
      this.filteredValues['client_name'] = ClientNameFilterValue;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filteredValues);
    });


    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.filterTable()

    this.customerService.getAllCustomers().subscribe(
      customers => {
        this.customers = customers;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>(this.customers);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      })
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string)
  {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  filterTable() {
    const myFilterPredicate = function(data: Customer, filter: string): boolean 
    {
      let searchString = JSON.parse(filter);
      return (
        data?.module_control?.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.module_control.toLowerCase()) !== -1 &&
        data?.client_name?.toString().trim().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString.client_name.toLowerCase()) !== -1
      );
    };
    return myFilterPredicate;
  }
}
```

Comment: you should toLowerCase when give value to filteredValues:`this.filteredValues['module_control'] = moduleControlFilterValue.toLowerValue();` && `this.filteredValues['client_name'] = ClientNameFilterValue.toLowerValue();` NOTE: you can use `this.filteredValues.client_name = ClientNameFilterValue.toLowerValue();` NOTE2: you can also create a formGroup and only subscribe to the formGroup. you can see an example in this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75374514/search-filter-in-a-material-angular-table-for-each-column/75374975#75374975)

Answer (score 1):

When you get the data you create a new `DataSource` in the subscription. It replace `this.dataSource.filterPredicate` value. It means that `MatTable` will use default own filter. But this filter gets JSON insead of simple string and can't find nothing like `{"client_name":"","module_control":"2"}`.

Your `filterTable()` wasn't used at all. You can check this, if `filterTable` function return true everywhere, it will not give any result.

So, you should add declaration of `filterPredicate` to your data subscription(or `valueChange` subscription)

```
this.customerService.getAllCustomers().subscribe(
      customers => {
        this.customers = customers;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Customer>(this.customers);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.filterTable(); // filter function was added
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(error.message);
      })
```