# Column filter on Angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Someone know if is possible to add column filter (like in the image attached) on the angular material table? I already search on the official documentation and i don't find anything useful.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49939979/5107490

Comment: Yes, you can add an input to each header
 <ng-container matColumnDef="client_name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Client name
        <div>
          <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput class="form-field" [formControl]="clientNameFilter" placeholder="Filter" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"/>
          </mat-form-field>
        </div>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.client_name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
Here is similar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75449883/multiple-filters-on-mattable-angular/75453709#75453709

Comment: thanks @NikitaBardakov, it works. Now i have another issue. Basically for all pages i use a generic material table (reusable component) and i'm trying to figure out on how to pass the filters for every column. To the generic table i pass the columns in an array like this [[
      {
        "headerCode": "employee_id",
        "property": "id",
        "sortBy": "id",
        "textAlign": "left",
        "size": "200",
        "include": "",
        "pipe": "",
        "format": "",
        "bolded": true
      }]. Maybe is a good idea to pass the html filter from here?

Comment: It's dificult to recomend something not seeing the whole project. But you can look at the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75449883/multiple-filters-on-mattable-angular/75453709#75453709 . There JSON used for miltiple filters. I guess you can use just an Object. It depends from your needs
I create a little SB example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dqmyop?file=src/main.ts
There is some bug, the table data doesn't appeared after  loading, and is needed click to filter. This example just show a way