# Angular table with multiple header column input filter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms

I have an Angular table with three columns. In the table header, all these three columns have three input fields.

Three inputs: Stock Number, Case, Availability.

User can search with Single Input(Stock Number OR Case OR Availability), two inputs(AND condition of any 2 inputs) or all three inputs(AND of all 3 inputs).

I have written code for 3 inputs scenario with AND operator. How to change this logic to all input usecases?

I am looking for a solution, where if the user enters three inputs {stockNumber: 'XYZ5000', caseNum: '1991', availability: 'AVAILABLE'}. It has to be compared with stockDetailsList(in stock response object) and collect the filtered result in another stock object(Just print filtered stock bject in console.log).

`AppComponent` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

const stock:any[] = [
  {
  stockId: 'XYZ5000', stockDetailsList: [
    {stockNumber: 'XYZ5000', caseNum: '1991', availability: 'AVAILABLE'},
    {stockNumber: 'XYZ5000', caseNum: '2001', availability: 'AVAILABLE'},
    {stockNumber: 'XYZ5000', caseNum: '2023', availability: 'AVAILABLE'},
    {stockNumber: 'XYZ5000', caseNum: '2000', availability: 'NOTAVAILABLE'},
    {stockNumber: 'XYZ5000', caseNum: '1997', availability: 'AVAILABLE'},
    {stockNumber: 'XYZ5000', caseNum: '2015', availability: 'AVAILABLE'}
    ],
  },
  {
  stockId: 'XYZ1000', stockDetailsList: [{stockNumber: 'XYZ1000', caseNum: '2015', availability: 'AVAILABLE'}
    ],
  },
  {
  stockId: 'XYZ4000, NEW.', stockDetailsList: [{stockNumber: 'XYZ4000', caseNum: '2012', availability: 'AVAILABLE'}
    ],
  }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'MultiInputFilters';
  stockForm!: FormGroup;
  pageList:any[] = [];
  public displayedColumns: string[] = ['stockId', 'caseNum', 'availability'];
  public dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
  
  constructor() {
    this.stockForm = new FormGroup({
      stockNumber: new FormControl(),
      caseNum: new FormControl(),
      availability: new FormControl(),
    });
  }

  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const objectArray: any[] = [];
    this.generateTableRows(stock, objectArray);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(objectArray);
  }
  
  public generateTableRows(stock: any[], objectArray: any[]): void {
    stock.forEach(s => {
      objectArray.push({ stockId: s.stockId });
      if (s.stockDetailsList?.length) {
        s.stockDetailsList.forEach((x: any) => objectArray.push({
          stockNumber: x.stockNumber,
          caseNum: x.caseNum,
          availability: x.availability,
        }))
      }
    });
    console.log('generateTableRows objectArray: '+ objectArray);
  }


  applyFilter() {
    this.pageList = [];
    const objectArray: any[] = [];
    const { stockNumber, caseNum , availability } = this.stockForm.value;
    this.pageList = stock.filter(s => {
      s.stockDetailsList.filter((x: any) => {

        if (((stockNumber && stockNumber.includes(x.stockNumber))) && (caseNum && caseNum.includes(x.caseNum)) && (availability && availability.includes(x.availability))) {
          objectArray.push({ stockId: s.stockId });
          objectArray.push({
            stockNumber: x.stockNumber,
            caseNum: x.caseNum,
            availability: x.availability,
          })
        }

      });
    });
    console.log("applyFilter objectArray: "+ objectArray);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(objectArray);
    //this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(objectArray); => this.dataSource.filter is preferable than MatTableDataSource
  }

}
```

Stackblitz of complete project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-38zpmg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,
https://angular-ivy-38zpmg.stackblitz.io

Technologies used:

- Angular
- TypeScript
- Angular Forms
- Angular Material

[image]

Comment: You don't need to have two arrays. Take a look, e.g. to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68495473/how-to-add-multiple-filters-in-angular-mat-table/68496521#68496521). Material angular has a filter property. The "key" is create a customFilter function. As this function only allow to you pass a string, you pass a JSON.stringify(yourForm.value). In the function you use JSON.parse(filter); to get an object and return true or false

Comment: I checked the example. Good Solution using customFilter function. Seems we have to add each filter in the 'and' condition and cannot add it dynamically when filter is growing?

Comment: I was thinking in a customFilter like the answer bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
customFilter = (data: PeriodicElement, filter: string) => {
    const filterData = JSON.parse(filter);
    //filterData will be like: {stockNumber:..,caseNum:..,availability:...,name:...}

    bool find=!filterData.stockNumber || filterData.stockNumber.includes(data.stockNumber);
    find=find && (!filterData.caseNum || filterData.caseNum.includes(data.caseNum)
    find=find && (!filterData.availability|| filterData.availability.includes(data.availability)
    find=find && (!filterData.name|| data.name.indexOf(filterData.name)>=0)
    return find
  };
```

Comment: customFilter is not called from ngOnInit as per stackblitz example. I am checking that.

Comment: @Abhikhya, I'm in hurry, but I forked your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1ccibo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). See that you subscribe to valueChanges, (don't use applyFilter). Sure has errors but I'm need go out. By

Comment: I was trying the same way given in stackblitz, but not working in local. Your stackblitz link is working. I will check it. Also my expectation is to return stockId as well. When filter is applied, Check the matching filter in child object(i.e., stockDetailsList) and return the stock object. So that I can iterate the stockId also later. Great Thanks for your time @Eliseo. I will proceed from here.